# Error when debugging Android app on Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, compiler-errors

Whenever I create a new Android app and debug it using Eclipse, the following error is returned:

```
[Emulator] unknown option: -n
```

The problem is that I don't know why it is passing -n. Is there a way to see what Eclipse is trying to input into the console, so as to allow me to rectify this error?

EDIT: I realized that in the Preferences, the default arguments is "-n Latest". I don't know why is this so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out the problem. It is because of the default settings the Android SDK sets. I have found a way to change it.